# how to change all bits in integer or byte

Tags: c#, bit-shift

what I'm trying to do is use XOR operand to bits in int so that

what is 0 is than 1¸and

what is 1 is than 0

I've read allot of articles for that and I just seem not to understand it

this is how I'm trying:

```
    public string text = "password";
    public string keypass = "s0";
    int[] x = new int[text.Length];

    ulong key = 255;
    char encript = ' ';
    x[0] = text[0];
    x[0] ^= x[0] << (int)key;
    encript = (char)x[0];
    keypass = x[0].ToString();
    text = encript.ToString();
```

it doesn't work

```
x[0] |= x[0] << (int)key;
x[0] &= x[0] << (int)key;
```

nothing what I try doesn't seem to work can someone help me here?

Comment: can you clarify, what exactly you expect? you have strings that seem irrelevant to your question. Include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Be careful to regard the transformed data as bytes, not as a string. It is possible that it will have sequences of bytes that are not valid for a Unicode string.

Comment: I hope you don't think this is actual encryption, it's completely insecure as far as that is concerned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To flip all bits in an 8-bit integer, XOR it with 0xFF, i.e. `x ^ 0xFF`.

Run the below snippet for "proof".

```js
function formatInt(i) {
  return `${i} (0x${i.toString(16).toUpperCase().padStart(2, '0')}) (${i.toString(2).padStart(8, '0')}b)`;
}

for(let i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
  var l = i ^ 0xFF;
  document.body.appendChild(Object.assign(document.createElement("div"), {innerText: `${formatInt(i)} ^ 0xFF = ${formatInt(l)}`}));
}
```

Comment: Or just use `~` instead - at least in C#.